# How to add a new collection to Firebase Firestore with Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, collections

How can I add a new collection with Firebase 9.8.2

```
methods: {
      registerUser(){
        const auth = getAuth();
        createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, this.user.email, this.user.password).then((datauser)=>{
         dbItemAdd.add({
          name: this.user.name,
          email: this.user.email,
          uid: datauser.user.uid,
        })
          router.push({
            name:'home'
          })
        }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error.code)
        switch (error.code) {
          case "auth/invalid-email":
            this.errMsg = "Invalid email";
            break;
          case "auth/weak-password":
            this.errMsg = "weak password";
            break;
          case "auth/email-already-in-use":
            this.errMsg = "email already in use";
            break;
        }
      })

      }
    },
```

Comment: What is not working on your code? If your `dbItemAdd` has a collection reference, it will automatically create a new collection with your new document.

Comment: const dbItemAdd = firebase.firestore().collection("products");
export { dbItemAdd };

Comment: the error message is : Compiled with problems:X ERROR in ./src/Firebase.js 3:0-32 Module not found: Error: Package path . is not exported from package /home/dataxplorer/projectvuejs/node_modules/firebase (see exports field in /home/dataxplorer/projectvuejs/node_modules/firebase/package.json)